# Get value of class attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to get the value of the class attribute:

```js
let postId = $("#miningProfChart").attr('class').val()

console.log(postId)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="miningProfChart" style="height: 250px;" class="333"></div>
```

Any suggestions why I get the error message?

I appreciate your replies!

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/attr

Comment: Remove `.val()`. When using `.attr(arg)`, the key accessed will return you the name of the arg. E.g. `<div id="myDiv" class="my-custom-class"></div>` - `$('#myDiv').attr('class')` will return `my-custom-class`. Read what @RoryMcCrossan mentioned.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need .val() for getting value of attributes. Also .val() function works for input type values only. And as the attr() function returns a string value, there is no such method as `.val()` on it, hence the error.

Just use `$("#miningProfChart").attr('class');`

Also keep your script tag at the end of the body after the jquery script because when your code was executing earlier, the Jquery library was not loaded yet.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="miningProfChart" style="height: 250px;" class="333"></div>

<script>
  let postId = $("#miningProfChart").attr('class');

  console.log(postId)
</script>
```

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs Done :)

Comment: huzzah shall remove comment :)